# Draw a JSON tree structure using jQuery without tree jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I m trying to develop **FAQs** page for my Spring MVC application.As amtter of fact i have FAQs as tree structure and when evern i click on one of te question. i have to be able to see the answer on the other answer pane i suppose using AJAX.

Since i want to draw a `tree` structure without using any `jquery tree plugin`  other than the main jquery library ,the jquery tree plugin since its almost **87K** and my web application doesn't need to included it due to its size , and for some reason i did not know the minify version is ?

But ,i want to draw a FAQ tree of the questions  using the `Jquery.min.js.` or pure java script if availbel but not `tree.jquery.js` which does pretty fine job if you would like to add it on your project.

If you want i will add the json question data.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: you need to write a recursive function, just try to create a <ul></ul> based on a depth or level property, you can do it even in pure javascript

Comment: Thanks , but my wonder is how colud one vote to close this question ?

Comment: The question is too broad. You do not provide any of your requirements (how to render the tree, what the code size limit is, ...). You could have provided some code that illustrates what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: why not just ask for clarity rather than vote the question closed ?

Comment: @user2808054 Because that is the way Stack Overflow works. If a question can be fixed, and someone fixes it, it will be reopened. This question is way too vague and broad in my opinion to be fixable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: how is it now ? i have seen vague question SOF but not closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method :

The tree is stored in a Javascript object with values:

"link" =a url
"title" =the text to show
"subOptions" = another tree list ith options under this list

like this ..

```
var tree=[
    {title:"One",link:"One.html",
         subOptions:[{title:"oneA",link:"OneA.ht,l"},
                     {title:"oneB",link:"OneB.html"}]
     },
    {title:"Two",link:"Two.html"},
    {title:"Three",link:"three.html"},
    ];
```

Then a small function to recursively travel the tree and build an HTML tree using  for indenting.

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tEgRL/4/

Add your own properties to enhance it, and style as you see fit.

This is obviously very basic, but it does draw a tree with links, usable as a menu.

While posing this I become aware that actually you haven't said much about what you want the tree to look like or what it's to be used for, and I have assumed you mean a "menu" kind of option tree.

Comment: give ur vote for reopen , this might save cost and time ,complexity in the future if its done as simple as this ...also we need to have css!!

Comment: hi danielad - not sure I follow you regards 'vote for reopen' ? did you want me to add more ?

Comment: Yes Sir , if possible yes , because there is no simple easy way to deal with this stuff some how despite you have started to give a simpel soultion for this ...if u understand what am saying

Comment: OK, added basic CSS and ability to style different levels in the tree.

Comment: Same JSFiddle =  http://jsfiddle.net/tEgRL/37/

Comment: Meanwhile could you edit the question to make it a bit clearer that it's for use as a FAW / navugation menu ? I thinmk that would persuade the powers that be that the question shoud be taken off 'hold'.